# i cant understanding negative 2 and positive 2 x=-10 % 4; System.out.println("-10% 4 : "+x); //-2

Tags: java

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x;

        x = -10 % 4;
        System.out.println("-10%  4 : " + x);   // -2 "explain this"

        x = -10 % -4;
        System.out.println("-10% -4 : " + x);   // -2 "explain this"

        x = 10 % -4;
        System.out.println("-10% -4 : " + x);   // 2 "explain this"

        x = 10 % 4;
        System.out.println("  10% 4 : " + x);   // 2 "explain this"
    }
}
```

I cant understand how to come (2,-2) plz explain it...

I cant understand negative 2 and positive 2 as the result of

```
x = -10 % 4;
System.out.println("-10%  4 : " + x);   // -2
```

Comment: Did you look up what the `%` operator does? Also: your 2nd and 3rd output does not match the calculated statement.

Comment: `%` calculates the [Rermainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder) //  @f1sh are you sure about 2nd and 3rd output?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes, the `println` statements do not match what was actually calculcated for `x`.

Comment: @f1sh I think I understand (could have been explained better) and I still cannot see what is wrong with 2nd print; third has an extra `-` in the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `%` divides the left side by the right side as `/` would do, **but the result is the remainder of the division** and not the result of the division itself.

See this example where your code was extended and slightly changed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    int y;

    x = -10 % 4; // calculates the remainder of...
    y = -10 / 4; // ... this calculation
    System.out.println("-10 /  4 = " + y + ", remainder: " + x);

    x = -10 % -4;
    y = -10 /- 4;
    System.out.println("-10 / -4 = " + y + ", remainder: " + x);

    x = 10 % -4;
    y = 10 / -4;
    System.out.println(" 10 / -4 = " + y + ", remainder: " + x);

    x = 10 % 4;
    y = 10 / 4;
    System.out.println(" 10 /  4 = " + y + ", remainder: " + x);
}
```

This outputs

```
-10 /  4 = -2, remainder: -2
-10 / -4 = 2, remainder: -2
 10 / -4 = -2, remainder: 2
 10 /  4 = 2, remainder: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in programming languages they do the following:

`-10%-4` is `-2`

`-5%2` is `-1`

`5%-2` is `1`

they look at the first thing (before the `%` sign) to determine the return value.
If it is negative, the answer is negative.  If it is positive, the answer is positive.

Comment: Or, to take into account what the `%` operator does, use the remainder of that statement. Which is either 0 or negative if the dividend is negative.

Answer (score 0):

What hasn't been addressed by the other answers (so far) is why `-10 % 4 = -2` and `10 % -4 = 2` while `-10 / 4 = -2` and `10 / -4 = -2`.

In division, if both dividend and divisor have the same sign (+/-) the result is positive. If they have different sign (one is positive the other negative) the result is negative.

As we can see from the result of the `%`-operator, that rule does not apply here. But why?

The `%`-operator is actually the following:

```
a % b = a - (a / b) * b
```

```
a = -10
b = -4
```

then gives

```
-10 - (-10 / -4) * -4 = -10 - (2) * -4 = -10 - -8 = -10 + 8 = -2
```

And the other alternatives

```
a = 10
b = 4
10 - (10 / 4) * 4 = 10 - (2) * 4 = 10 - 8 = 2

a = -10
b = 4
-10 - (-10 / 4) * 4 = -10 - (-2) * 4 = -10 - -8 = -10 + 8 = -2

a = 10
b = -4
10 - (10 / -4) * -4 = 10 - (-2) * -4 = 10 - 8 = 2
```